# Botão para forçar Download sem mostrar seu caminho

Tags: php, html5, button, link, download

Olá,

Tenho um site html principal meusite.com que pode ser encontrado pelos robôs dos buscadores e fiz o meusite.com/download.html com estes parâmetros`<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noodp, noarchive, noimageindex">` para não ser encontrado nos buscadores e onde quero criar um botão de download para os arquivos .PDF .DOC e .DOCX sem que a pessoa veja o caminho do arquivo `<a href="http://meusite.com/download/arquivo.pdf">`, sem que esse arquivo possa ser indexado pelos buscadores e sem que a pessoa consiga fazer o download digitando por exemplo meusite.com/download/arquivo.pdf
Encontrei algumas informações na internet via php, mas a maioria atrelada a necessidade de criar um login na pagina de download.
A ideia é passar este link (meusite.com/download.html) para algumas pessoas e que elas possam fazer o download apenas por lá.

- Coloquei os arquivos de download fora do public_html para dificultar o acesso direto até eles por exemplo com https://meusite.com/download/arquivo.doc
- Tenho como fazer um botão de download sem mostrar o link direto e se possível renomeando o arquivo ex: 759345798357934.pdf para arquivo1.pdf e sdjfhksdjfksdjf.doc para arquivo2.doc dificultando a busca por esse arquivo?
- Tenho como criar um segundo botão visualizar PDF no próprio navegador sem também mostrar o caminho real e mudando o seu nome?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer o PHP repassar o arquivo pra ele mesmo e alteração do cabeçalho poderá tornar o *download* automático:

**pdf.php**
No atributo **filename=** você define o nome de download para o arquivo que seja diferente do original.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
    // Exemplo de buscar o arquivo
        $file = "./contos_de_fadas/".$_GET['id'].".pdf";
    // Cabeçalho PDF
    $dl="inline";
    if(isset($_GET['download'])){$dl="attachment";}
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header("Content-Disposition: ".$dl."; filename=nome_falso.pdf");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    @readfile($file);
}else{
    echo "Nenhuma ID selecionada";
}
?>
```

**Exemplo no HTML+JAVASCRIPT:**

```js
function pdfView(t){
document.location = "pdf.php?id="+t.name;
}
function pdfDownload(t){
document.location = "pdf.php?id="+t.name+"&download";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="pdfView(this)" name="chapeusinho_vermelho" value="Chapéusinho Vermelho" />
<input type="button" onclick="pdfDownload(this)" name="chapeusinho_vermelho" value="Download" />
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="pdfView(this)" name="tres_porquinhos" value="Os Três Porquinhos" />
<input type="button" onclick="pdfDownload(this)" name="tres_porquinhos" value="Download" />
<br>
```

Dessa maneira não só os links ficarão ocultos, mas o gerenciador de downloads do usuário também não terá acesso a não ser pelo PHP.